# Knockout save variable inside template

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a `jquery knockout` template which renders a `foreach`.

Inside each item, i am using the same function many times (for `css` binding and for visibility of other child elements)

Is it possible that instead of calling the same function many times for each item in the `foreach`, to temporary save it and then re-use it inside the template?

PS: i know i can set the visibility of the `<i class="fa " />` tags using css selectors, but this doesn't answers the question.

```
<script type="text/html" id="properties-template">
    <!-- ko foreach: Groups -->

        <!-- saving the result in a variable instead of calling it so many times -->
        <!-- var isValid = isGroupValid($data); !-->

        <div class="group" data-bind="css: { 'valid': isGroupValid($data) }">
            <div class="iconContainer">
                <!-- ko if: $root.isGroupValid($data) === false -->
                    <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko if: $root.isGroupValid($data) === true -->
                    <i class="fa fa-check-square"></i>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `$data` is itself the viewmodel, you could just have a computed observable there which does whatever logic `isGroupValid` currently does. So I assume your view model at the moment looks something like

```
function ViewModel(){
   this.isGroupValid = function(data){
      // some logic returning boolean
   }
}
```

Here's a live example demonstrating the "before": http://jsfiddle.net/hbSj7/

change it to this:

```
function ViewModel(){
   this.isGroupValid = ko.computed(function(){
      // some logic returning boolean
      // just use "this" where you used to use "data"
   }, this);
}
```

Then just change your template to, eg/

```
<div class="group" data-bind="css: { 'valid': isGroupValid() }">
    <div class="iconContainer">
        <!-- ko if: !isGroupValid() -->
            <i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: isGroupValid() -->
            <i class="fa fa-check-square"></i>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a live example having changed to this method: http://jsfiddle.net/ug9ax/

The important difference is in your current method the function gets executed every time you call it, with the changed method the computed only gets re-evaluated if anything it depends on changes, like other observable properties in your viewmodel.

Comment: This works, thanks. I'll change to `ko.computed`. Other than this, is possible to create variables in templates? (saying that at one moment maybe i'll need them)

Comment: I dont think so, although the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) describes using other templating engines and they may well support variables.